# await not doing what I expect

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```
async function doThings() {
    async function timer () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('timer!')
        }), 1000
    }
    
    async function printer () {
        console.log('printer!')
    }

    await timer()
    await printer()
}

doThings()
```

I thought making the function async made it return a promise and await made it wait. Why does printer() finish first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a Promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved Promise automatically.

Now when we use don't return Promise from async function, then javascript interpreter automatically returns resolved Promise, so that is the reason await on timer function got the resolved Promise and interpreter went ahead with the execution, but there is a setTimeout still going on. So we have to return a Promise from timer function, and resolve it inside setTimeout function like below.

```
async function doThings() {

    async function timer() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(`timer!`);
                resolve();
            }, 1000)
        });
    }

    async function printer() {
        console.log('printer!')
    }

    await timer()
    await printer()
}

doThings()
```

Comment: So if we don't explicitly return a promise from an async function it automatically returns a resolved promise which makes await not work as it resolves immediately? I think I understand, but what use is that?

Comment: Yes async functions return resolved promise if explicitly is not returned from the function, so the caller await resolves it immediately. And yes it is just a better readability and easy to work with Promises, nothing more nothing less. It is as good as using then on returned Promise. But chaining in Promises makes the code more complex to read. Async/await makes the code simpler. Lets take your code only as example, it would look like this ---
timer().then(function successmethod(){ printer() },function failuremethod(){})

Answer (score 1):

Your `timer` function doesn't work because setTimeout does not return a promise that could be awaited. You will need to promisify it manually:

```
// set a default of 1500
function timeout(ms=1500) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

async function printer() {
  console.log('printer!');
};

async function doThings() {
  await timeout(1000); // time in ms
  await printer();
};

doThings();
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can see is timer () and printer () functions are async functions but there is no await used in them, and this makes the async keyword unfunctional.